# Github actions: setup environment variable in Windows being prefix by "C:/Program Files/Git"

Tags: github-actions

I have this weird problem where I do setup a bunch of environment variables using

```
echo "deltaKustoClusterId=${{ secrets.CLUSTER_ID }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

For this specific one the environment variable get prefixed by `C:/Program Files/Git`.
That is, if the secret is `123`, the environment variable seen by an exec running after is `C:/Program Files/Git123`.

Now the weird thing is that it just happens on Windows.  I have the exact same job for Linux, Windows and MacOS.  I literally copy-paste the job code bet OS.

I've also tried resetting the secret to no avail.  I have no idea where this "C:/Program Files/Git" could be coming from.

Am I missing something?